# Salesforce Access Key Token generation through SSIS

Tags: ssis, salesforce

I'm trying to generate a Salesforce Access Token through the Refresh Token in SSIS using a Script task with C# code.
But I'm having an error generating the code. Actually C# throws an error on this line

> "token = ser.Deserialize(result);"

Here is the code which I used:

```
{
 string URI = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";
 StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

 body.Append("refresh_token=" + refreshToken + "&");
 body.Append("grant_type=refresh_token&");
 body.Append("client_id=" + clientID + "&");
 body.Append("client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&");
 body.Append("redirect_uri=" + redirectURL);

 string result = HttpPost(URI, body.ToString());

 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 token = ser.Deserialize<TokenResponse>(result);
}
```

I want to generate the access token and save into a variable.

Comment: please share what is the error that you are getting.

Comment: @observer I approved your edit. When editing, please also [remove things like "Thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333).

Comment: Hi Barth, the error is related to namespace could not be found "TokenResponse".